# JavaScript "window.onload" – is "window" really necessary?

Tags: javascript, events, function, window

I see people use "window.onload" all the time, but why? Isn't the "window" part completely superfluous?

Comment: Depends pn your context.

Comment: I should clarify that I am in the window scope. Within the window scope, isn't it just as superfluous as using window.document or window dot anything, for that matter?

Comment: @sfjedi - it is not worth the risk and lack of clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't, then the onload method will be attributed to the current object, whatever that is (if any). So sometimes it may work, but writing window.onload is the most explicit, specific and safe way to do it.

Comment: Right. "onload" is not exclusively used for the window object. It can be used on images and other objects as well. Therefore window should always be specified.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an implied this, so it would only collide with another onload variable if it's a local variable or you are inside a "with ([some object with an onload property]) block.

Answer (score 0):

[link text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)
"The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading."

need to start working with the full DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    if(window.addEventListener){
        window.addhandler= function(who, which, what){
            return who.addEventListener(which, what, false);
        }
    }
    else if(window.attachEvent){
        window.addhandler= function(who, which, what){
            return who.addEventListener('on'+which, what);
        }
    }        
    function somefunction(){
        alert('page loaded')  
    }    
    addhandler(window,'load',somefunction);    
</script>
```